# How to send a url in form-data as a file using js or axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, blob

Am using vuejs and axios to send formdata to somelink.The file not sending and am getting the error

```
The parameter 'file' had the following problems: file transferred without multipart should be base64 encoded
```

I did change the data.append('file', url) and added another parameter to be like     data.append('file', url,{type:'pdf'}) but then i get an error that say the second parameter is not a blob.
I know that the issue is caused because i use a url inside a file and this i cannot change because the api document that am sending files to require to send formdata with file so am trying to replace the file with a live url

```
var data = new FormData();
        var url= 'https://storage.cloudconvert.com/xxxxx.pdf';
        data.append('name','file')
        data.append('filename', 'amjad');
        data.append('file', url);
        data.append('saved', 'true');
        data.append('type', 'pdf');
        axios.post('myapiurl',data, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },

        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file and then encoding it.. something like this..

```
 function getPdf(){
        // read text from URL location
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'https://storage.cloudconvert.com/xxxxx.pdf', true);
        request.send(null);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                var type = request.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
                if (type.indexOf("pdf") !== 1) {
                    return request.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
// Encode the String
    var pdf = btoa(getPdf()); 
    
    
    var data = new FormData();
           
            data.append('name','file')
            data.append('filename', 'amjad');
            data.append('file', pdf);
            data.append('saved', 'true');
            data.append('type', 'pdf');
            axios.post('myapiurl',data, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                },
    
            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            })
```